# Update rows in a table based on grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with records of the same type with ID's  and a grouping. I need to update the id's of table 1 into table 2 based on the record id from largest to smallest using the position.

Table 1

| ID | Group | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Apple |
| 2 | A | Apple |
| 3 | B | Apple |
| 4 | B | Apple |

Table 2

| ID | recordid | position | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 250 | A |
| 2 | 2 | 350 | A |
| 3 | null | 450 | A |
| 4 | null | 550 | A |
| 5 | 3 | 250 | B |
| 6 | 4 | 350 | B |
| 7 | null | 450 | B |
| 8 | null | 550 | B |

```
update table2
set recordid=T1.ID
From Table1 T1
join Table2 T2 on T2.Group=T1.Group
```

This isn't distinct so I don't think it's right, but I can't figure it out.
where ?????

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.)

Comment: The dbms is mysql or well I'm using sql server management studio

Comment: Those two aren't fully compatible...

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio only works with Microsoft SQL Server, not with MySQL. So which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you have multiple Id per group , so you have to choose one :

```
update table2
set recordid= ( select top 1 T1.ID
                From Table1 T1
                join Table2 T2 on T2.Group=T1.Group
               )
where recordid is null
```